# strpos() in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, strpos

In PHP there's a useful `strpos` function that finds the position of first occurrence of a string. 
Is there a similar way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
str.index(pattern)
```

Use the [index() method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001142). This will return the index if found, otherwise return nil.

Usage:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :036 > str = "Ruby is awesome"
 => "Ruby is awesome" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :037 > str.index("is awesome")
 => 5 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :038 > str.index("testtest")
 => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
>> "abc".index("b")
=> 1
```

or

```
>> "acdfeb".match("f").begin(0)
=> 3
```